# Can't copy paste between windows 10 to centos 7 in VMware workstation, how to fix this issue?

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, vmware

I've windows 10 installed as primary Operating System. Inside it, using vmware workstation 17, I've installed centos 7.
Now, for eg: I want to copy the command to download mysql workbench in centos 7.
For eg: from this site:
https://snapcraft.io/install/mysql-workbench-community/centos

How do I copy paste? Ctrl+C->Ctrl+V obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Going to VMware options and enabling folder sharing fixed the issue for me.
[image]

Reference:

The answer by Sheetal Kaul given here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32613629

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to copy and paste files between a Windows 10 host and a CentOS 7 virtual machine running on VMWare Workstation, there are a few things you can try to resolve the issue.

First, make sure that you have the latest version of VMWare Tools installed in the virtual machine. You can do this by selecting "VM" from the VMWare Workstation menu, then selecting "Install VMWare Tools". If you already have VMWare Tools installed, try reinstalling it to make sure it is up to date.

If you have an older version of VMWare Tools installed or have difficulty installing it, you can try using the open-vm-tools package instead. To install open-vm-tools, you can run the following command in the terminal of your CentOS 7 virtual machine:

```
sudo yum install open-vm-tools
```

Once you have installed or updated VMWare Tools, you may also need to configure your virtual machine settings to enable "Shared Folders" between the host and virtual machine. To do this, go to "VM" > "Settings" within VMWare Workstation, select "Options", then select "Shared Folders". From there, you can add a new shared folder or edit existing ones.

If you're still unable to copy and paste files between the host and virtual machine, you can try manually transferring files using a file transfer protocol such as Secure Copy (SCP) or File Transfer Protocol (FTP).

Overall, these steps should help you to resolve the issue and enable you to copy and paste files between your Windows 10 host and CentOS 7 virtual machine running on VMWare Workstation.